# How do I test a Rails Engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm writing an engine that interacts with the initialization process of the app. I need to simulate the app boot/start to check if some initializers were loaded etc.

How do I test this Rails boot/start like a new application booting?

Comment: If you're using Rails 3.1 then I think the new plugin generator should generate a dummy app in your test directory. You can write an integration test that will start the dummy app which will use your engine. If you're not using 3.1 yet, the the [Enginex gem](https://github.com/josevalim/enginex) shows you the necessary modifications that you need to make to get the same functionality. Here's [an example](http://www.arailsdemo.com/posts/43) using the Enginex gem.

Answer (score 3):

I always create a dummy Rails app in the test folder of my gems and test the gem through the app.

Same for engines, declare it with :path in the gemfile